# Can’t find breaker for AC unit

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, electrical-panel

I have 2 AC units and I’m installing Ecobee thermostats. The upstairs unit is on the main panel and I was able to turn it off and install the thermostat.

I turned off the main breaker and the downstairs unit continues to run so it’s obviously not on the main panel. Outside by the unit it is hooked up to a box from the Electric company that says shouldn’t be opened.

I’ve had the thermostat replaced on this unit before and I know they didn’t call the electric company to open this box.

Is there somewhere else this unit may be wired to or somewhere else it can be turned off?

[image: outside panel]

Answer (score 2):

That Duke Energy box is a remote load controller that allows Duke to power down your unit for some interval during times of peak load.  Generally you get some sort of discount for allowing them to do that.

But it's NOT the circuit breaker.  That is going to be in the main panel or a sub-panel.  Trace the wiring coming into the load controller back to the source of the power.